# ant -f build.xml run vs ant -f build jar

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

Can anyone please tell me what is the technical difference between,

1-

```
ant -f build.xml run
```

and

2-

```
ant -f build.xml jar
java -jar project.jar
```

I'm asking this because my application runs flawlessly with I run it with the number "1" command

BUT

Comes up with a whole lot of exceptions when is run as a jar file (Number 2 command set).

Any explanation for this??!  I just want to know why the application responds differently to these two situations???!

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for -->
<!-- some examples of how to customize the build. -->
<!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) -->
<!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. -->
<!-- Commands such as Run, Debug, and Test only use this build script if -->
<!-- the Compile on Save feature is turned off for the project. -->
<!-- You can turn off the Compile on Save (or Deploy on Save) setting -->
<!-- in the project's Project Properties dialog box.-->
<project name="LMB" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project LMB.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--

    There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
    used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
    before and after some main targets. They are: 

      -pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties
      -post-init:                called after initialization of project properties
      -pre-compile:              called before javac compilation
      -post-compile:             called after javac compilation
      -pre-compile-single:       called before javac compilation of single file
      -post-compile-single:      called after javac compilation of single file
      -pre-compile-test:         called before javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -post-compile-test:        called after javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -pre-compile-test-single:  called before javac compilation of single JUnit test
      -post-compile-test-single: called after javac compilation of single JUunit test
      -pre-jar:                  called before JAR building
      -post-jar:                 called after JAR building
      -post-clean:               called after cleaning build products

    (Targets beginning with '-' are not intended to be called on their own.)

    Example of inserting an obfuscator after compilation could look like this:

        <target name="-post-compile">
            <obfuscate>
                <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            </obfuscate>
        </target>

    For list of available properties check the imported 
    nbproject/build-impl.xml file. 


    Another way to customize the build is by overriding existing main targets.
    The targets of interest are: 

      -init-macrodef-javac:     defines macro for javac compilation
      -init-macrodef-junit:     defines macro for junit execution
      -init-macrodef-debug:     defines macro for class debugging
      -init-macrodef-java:      defines macro for class execution
      -do-jar-with-manifest:    JAR building (if you are using a manifest)
      -do-jar-without-manifest: JAR building (if you are not using a manifest)
      run:                      execution of project 
      -javadoc-build:           Javadoc generation
      test-report:              JUnit report generation

    An example of overriding the target for project execution could look like this:

        <target name="run" depends="iDA-impl.jar">
            <exec dir="bin" executable="launcher.exe">
                <arg file="${dist.jar}"/>
            </exec>
        </target>

    Notice that the overridden target depends on the jar target and not only on 
    the compile target as the regular run target does. Again, for a list of available 
    properties which you can use, check the target you are overriding in the
    nbproject/build-impl.xml file. 

    -->
</project>
```

And here is the manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0-b147 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar lib/appf
 ramework-1.0.3.jar lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.ja
 r lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar lib/commons-log
 ging-1.1.1.jar lib/derby.jar lib/derbyLocale_cs.jar lib/derbyLocale_d
 e_DE.jar lib/derbyLocale_es.jar lib/derbyLocale_fr.jar lib/derbyLocal
 e_hu.jar lib/derbyLocale_it.jar lib/derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar lib/derbyLo
 cale_ko_KR.jar lib/derbyLocale_pl.jar lib/derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar lib/d
 erbyLocale_ru.jar lib/derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar lib/derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar
  lib/derbyclient.jar lib/derbynet.jar lib/derbyrun.jar lib/derbytools
 .jar lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar lib/httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar lib/http
 core-4.1.2.jar lib/httpmime-4.1.2.jar lib/jdom.jar lib/orangevolt-ant
 -tasks-1.3.8.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: lmb.LMBApp
```

NOTE:
Here I FOUND THE SOURCE OF THIS ISSUE BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIX IT,

Everything about library referencing and environment variables are ok except the fact that I'm not getting my SSL connection to the server while launching the jar file whereas the connection is easily made while running the application from inside Netbeans.  In fact I'm getting this following Exception when executing through the final jar fine,

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
```

PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS

Comment: You'll need to post your build.xml before anyone can really answer this for you

Comment: The *real* build file--you see that's almost all comments, right?

Comment: That's the build file generated by Netbeans.  I didn't add anything to it!

Comment: I understand. The first one just wasn't helpful, for obvious reasons. Are you running it from the root path?

Comment: As I posted this build file I noticed that it is trying to import a file called "build-impl.xml".  This file contains a lot of build code which I can't just post on the question are.  I can send it to your email if it helps identifying the problem.  I run this from the Project folder located in my "My Document" folder in Windows!

Comment: This question seems to be a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833808/application-compiles-and-builds-on-netbeans-but-not-as-an-independent-jar-file. Some of the same questions being asked here of @Sam have already been asked in the original, with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the first one uses a compilation (or execution) classpath, while the second one relies on an environment classpath (the jar doesn't include all your app's dependencies).

Comment: How can I make sure that the jar file is also meeting all the dependencies??!  I have a manifest file that ant includes with the jar file that is seemingly pointing to all my jar libraries located in my lib directory.  What else do you think is missing??!

Comment: @Sam No clue, without knowing anything about the build or execution environment, the actual manifest contents, etc. it's tough to say.

Comment: @Sam VM options? I'm not aware there's any mechanism to apply VM arguments from a jar, but that doesn't mean there isn't. IMO it wouldn't make much sense, though, unless they were overridable by immediate args to the `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

All of the items in your manifest need to be added to the classpath call.

This may contain a list of dependency jars which you could include on the command line using the -classpath options

```
java -cp gen/jars/test.jar -jar project.jar
```

You could inline the Ant build.xml and/or exceptions thrown so we can give you more information.

Comment: I've included the build.xml file at the end of my question.  I hope you could rescue me from this dread lock!

Comment: @Sam Uh... try again. Ugh, NetBeans ant file :( I wish people wouldn't rely on those.